# How to evaluate sympy symbolic function with multiple inputs

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to use sympy to solve a function symbolically, then input the values in and solve it numerically. I can do this with just one variable, but can't figure out how to do it with multiple. Here is what I have so far.

```
v,v0,a,t = sp.var('v v0 a t')
args = [v0,a,t]
arg_vals = [1,-9.81,2]

def get_function():
    v = v0 + a*t
    return v

def get_derivative(fun,var):
    derivative = sp.diff(fun,var)
    return derivative

def get_integral(fun,var):
    integral = sp.integrate(fun,var)
    return integral

def eval_function(fun, args, arg_vals):
    i=0
    for i in range(len(arg_vals)):
        args[i] = arg_vals[i]
    return fun.evalf(subs={args})

v = get_function()
a = get_derivative(v,t)
x = get_integral(v,t)

x_eval = eval_function(v,args,arg_vals)
```

The code runs fine until it hits the eval_function return fun.evalf(subs={args}). Then I get

```
>>>TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and guess that someone can just take a few seconds and tell me I'm dumb lol. Thanks for the help!!

(using anaconda, spyder, python 3)

Comment: You can't do `subs={args}` when `args` is a list. If you want a set of the args-entries, you must "apply" them like `subs={*args}`. But it looks like you want a dictionary of args as keys, and arg_vals as values. You can get this with `d = { k : v for k,v in zip(args, arg_vals)}`. You can read more on the `subs` argument [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/evalf.py#L1363).